# textfield fires EditingChanged three times?

Tags: ios, textfield

This is when i input "input" and click the return button.

[image]

```
[_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (IBAction)textFieldValueChanged:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",_textField.text);
}
```

Comment: why return button fires it twice?I even set the textFieldShouldReturn Delegate NO.

Comment: Put some code for easy understand